# Deduce $\int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}2 \sin^n x dx = \frac{n-1}n \int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}2 \sin^{n-2} x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How do I deduce this?$$\int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}2 \sin^n x dx = \frac{n-1}n \int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}2 \sin^{n-2} x dx$$

I have used the reduction formula for the first part to obtain $$\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\frac{1}{n} \cos{x} \cdot \sin^{n - 1}{x} + \frac{n - 1}{n} \int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \ dx$$

Hence I compared both parts and got $$-\frac{1}{n} ((\cos\frac{\pi}2 \cdot \sin^{n - 1}\frac{\pi}2)-(\cos(0) \cdot \sin^{n - 1}(0))  = 0$$

I'm not sure if my third step is correct as I am unable to obtain a correct value for n as it equals to 0 in my third equation, but substituting it back into the first equation, I get $\frac{n-1}n $ to be undefined.

Comment: This gives a recurrence relation $I_n=\frac{n-1}n I_{n-2}$. What is it for,say, $n=3$ ?